# Limits of parallelization regarding the core number

Tags: c++, gcc, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm developing a parallel algorithm on a Intel i5-core machine, which has two cores, four threads.

n defines the size of the matrix, on which I perform my calculations on. As you can see from the table below there is almost 50% reduction from 1 thread to 2 threads utilization, but almost no difference between 2 threads and 4 threads. The numbers denote the seconds passed

[image: #of threads - computation time]

My compiler is mingw-gcc on windows platform. My parallelization tool is openmp. I'm defining number of threads by `omp_set_num_threads(numThreads);`in the beginning of the parallel routine.

I have no means to test the algorithm on a "real" 8 core machine. On my i5 machine, At 1 thread, task manager shows 25% of the total cpu power is used. At 2 threads, it's 50%, and at 4 threads, it's 96-99% as expected.

So what might be the reason for that situation? Why doesn't the computation time get halved?

The parallel code segment is to be found below:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(guided) shared(L,A) \
    private(i)
    for (i=k+1;i<row;i++){
        double dummy = 0;
        for (int nn=0;nn<k;nn++){
            dummy += L[i][nn]*L[k][nn];
            L[i][k] = (A[i][k] - dummy)/L[k][k];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might be memory-limited.  Or you might have two many dependencies between iterations.  BTW, is this a Cholesky decomposition?

Comment: Have you compared having independent/private arrays/thread vs shared?

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth Yes this is part of a Cholesky decomposition algorithm. But I don't think that I'm memory limited. when n=5000, the computer utilizes 362 MB of my 4 GB capacity.

Comment: @EmreTurkoz: I mean memory bandwidth.  You're doing very little computation per memory access.

Comment: @gbulmer: No I haven't. What should I try exactly?

Comment: Roughly: if the values are already in cache most of the time, then using two threads instead of one won't give much benefit; similarly, if the bottleneck is memory access more threads won't help. Threads might help if there is spare memory bandwidth, **and** using the thread causes more values to get loaded into cache/unit time.

Comment: @Emre Turkoz - I think Oli is correct, there isn't enough computation happening, so you might be memory-bandwidth limited. But, I was thinking of "splitting" the array into 4 parts, i.e. accessing widely seperate parts, and and using a thread on each. If there is plenty of memory bandwidth and it is CPU bound (which I don't expect), then making the parts 'independent' might give the hardware the chance interleave memory loading better. I honestly think there is too little computation vs memory access, so I don't expect much change, but it might be worth a little test.

Comment: Actually, there's a division in the inner loop. So that kinda automatically makes it expensive.

Comment: @gbulmer: Unfortunately, there is a nasty chain of dependencies in a Cholesky decompostion.  You start in one corner, and work your way outwards.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - yes. There may be three paths: 1- No matter what, it is memory limited, so there is no more CPU throughput (my suspicion); 2- There is memory bandwidth, and more threads might improve performance, but you won't see it in this program, so try something similar but different to find out. 3- There is memory bandwidth, but there is no program to solve the problem which will be able to use more threads. I am simply suggesting do something simpler to discover if 2 is even possible. Might be a small amount of work, and failure would suggest that it is class 1 or 3. Is that clear??

Comment: @ Mysticial - right, and you've explained to the OP how to get an improvement by hoisting the `/`. I think the OP is asking about cores & threads. IMHO, unless the OP can show their is plenty of spare memory bandwidth (probably no), and it doesn't become cache-bound (probably no), more threads can't help much. As Oli wrote, that algorithm can't easily be partitioned. Unless there are plenty of spare resources, there is  no point trying a slightly slower but parallelisable algorithm either. Does my reasoning make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your machine has ***2 cores*** and ***4 threads***.

You only have 2 ***cores***, so you won't get 4x speedup from 1 - 4 threads.

Secondly, as you scale to more threads, you will likely start hitting resource contention such as maxing out your memory bandwidth.

Comment: But I should get some speed-up right? I mean it's 50% vs. 100% cpu usage according to the task manager. So 4 threads must utilize some of the sources which are idle at 2 threads-case.

Comment: You *are* getting some speedup. `177.669` -> `162.182` Although small, that's a pretty typical amount for Hyperthreading. If you post your full test code, I can run this on some of my machines: 4-core/8-thread, 8-core/8-thread, 16-core/16-thread...

Comment: Thanks. I believe I should rent some hpc to test the scalability of my code. Computers at home don't give a clue about that.

Comment: Other than that, I'd say your code exhibits very good locality as long as one dimension fits into cache. Most attempts to parallelize matrix operations drop dead at the beginning because they're hopping cache-lines in the inner loop.

Comment: Another thing you might want to try is to hoist the division by `L[k][k]` outside of both loops. (Compute its reciprocal, and do a multiplication in the inner loop instead.) That'll probably speed it up dramatically, but it doesn't help you parallelize.

Comment: I carried the division outside of the inner loop. It indeed caused a speed up. Thanks

Comment: Yes, hyperthreading has been shown to have a maximum of 8-10% speedup vs the same number of cores non-hyperthreaded.